# Java HTTP Request

Tags: java, http-post, http-request

I' m trying to setup an httprequest using java.

Let's say i want to have something like this:

```
POST /TEST/PATH HTTP/1.1
[...]
```

I want to get the /TEST/PATH behind "POST".
I didn't find any setter to define that.
When I execute the request, the request sending looks like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
[...]
```

My Code looks like this:

```
SOAPServerAddress = "http://example.com/TEST/PATH";

// setup HTTP POST
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().build();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SOAPServerAddress);

// execute http request 
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Seems that you defined everything correctly. You are using `HttpPost`, so the HTTP method is indeed POST, your URL matches one that you want to get. Did you try to run your code? If not, try it. If yes, what's wrong?

Comment: I want the header to look like this: POST /TEST/PATH. But everything I get is POST /. Do you know a setter to define this? Is there anything?

Comment: Do you want to say that your request is sent to wrong URL, i.e. to `/` instead of `TEST/PATH`?

Comment: How do you know that this is what you get? How are you testing?

Comment: @Alex: no the request is getting sent to the right URL but the header have to look like the upper one.

Comment: @bmargulies: i'm using the tcp/ip monitor in eclipse

Comment: @Chris, it is impossible. If your request arrives to "correct" URL the HTTP packet must be OK. Otherwise it cannot arrive to right URL because this is what HTTP server does: it parses the HTTP headers. Try to use wireshark to see review your packets.